# Not able to access minikube dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I installed `minikube` with the below command:

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

Then, I start `minikube` cluster using

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

When I try to access the dashboard I see the error

**minikube dashboard**

> Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Error validating service: Error getting service kubernetes-dashboard: Get https://10.0.2.15:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

I set the proxy using

```
set NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15
```

Still same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you check if the dashboard pod is up and running `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` ?

Comment: $kubectl get pods

Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout.

Comment: can you check the status of VM with `minikube status` ?

Comment: chinmayee@chinmayee-VirtualBox:~$ sudo minikube status
minikube: Running
cluster: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 10.0.2.15

Comment: As I understand, VM is up and running however kubectl, minikube is not able to communicate with the API server. So Can you check `kubectl config view`? if client is referring to correct API-server's IP and Port.

Comment: $ sudo kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/chinmayee/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://10.0.2.15:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/chinmayee/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/chinmayee/.minikube/client.key

Comment: @SureshVishnoi : Any idea?

Comment: Hi, I am curious to know why are you using `--vm-driver=none ` this flag to start minikube ?

Comment: $ minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
140.01 MB / 140.01 MB [============================================]    
100.00% 0s
E1108 02:38:25.792900   17062 start.go:150] Error starting host: Error  creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ')

Comment: Got the above error, so used vm-driver=none.

Comment: chinmayee@chinmayee-VirtualBox:~$ sudo minikube dashboard
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Error validating service: Error getting service kubernetes-dashboard: Get https://10.0.2.15:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Comment: @SureshVishnoi : any help?

Comment: I think Usually I use Minikube with `virtual box` it works for me. If you can try with virtual box and lets see how it goes.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi : Yes i have a VM created on Oracle VirtualBox. It has ubuntu running. I am running on this.

Comment: So you need to use another Virtual box inside that ubuntu VM in order to create a minikube node. It's quite nested Virtualization. I would suggest you run minikube directly on the host machine rather than nested VM.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi : vm-driver=none -  this driver can be used to run the Kubernetes cluster components on the host instead of in a VM. This is what i see in the git-hub documentation. I am starting kubernetes cluster using this driver

Comment: Hi can you give me reference of the docs ? I would like to check it as well. thanks

Comment: @SureshVishnoi : https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube

Comment: @SureshVishnoi : Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: This probably doesn't apply to this specific instance so I am not posting it as an answer, but for anyone who happens along this post and has the TLS handshake timeout on Azure this is a known issue with more details over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726534/unable-to-connect-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-why-cant-kubectl-connect

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I was behind corporate proxy, adding `minikube ip` to the `no_proxy` env variable on host machine solved the issue.

```
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,$(minikube ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue, and for me it was happening because minikube VM was short of memory that was allocated.

Increasing Minikube RAM or deleting some exiting deployment, should resolve this issue.

To increase RAM configured for Minikube VM, use below command:

```
minikube config set memory 4096
```

After this, there would be need for minikube to stop, delete, and start using below commands.

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start
```

Comment: Your answer might be applicable for some users in the future but ideally you should provide the commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users change the visualization. for me this worked:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=docker
```